# Guice Multibinding from Classpath

Tags: java, cucumber, classpath, guice

I'm trying to setup a plugin system for cucumber-jvm bindings with Guice as DI. The idea is to run a **beforeRequest()** method before each **When** step in Cucumber. Plugins are separate .jar found in the classpath.

Since Cucumber requires an explicit [Guice module](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di#guice) declaration in cucumber.properties, that will be used to create an Injector, I can not use standard Guice [Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings) and have a separate Module per Plugin.

An idea how it should look like:

```
class CucumberClazz {

   Set<Plugin> plugins;

   public doRequest() {
     for(Plugin plugin: plugins) plugin.beforeRequest();
     /* Rest of the code */
   } 
}
```

Is there a fancy option to discover all implementations of Plugin in the classpath with Guice?

Comment: Not in guice, but you could use something like [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Comment: Why using Guice multibindings is not an option ?